# An old game for 3 players, the earliest records of which date back to

Tags: word-choice, meaning, translation

There is a game older than 3000 years. I would need to write it the way that the earliest records (or mentioning, notes?) are from that time.

> Something like: X is a game for three players with the earliest
>   records appearing around 1500 B.C.

But it does not sound that much right.

Comment: _X is a game for three players. It first appeared around 1500 B.C._ If you want it as a single sentence, use a semi-colon.

Comment: The phrasing in your question title looks fine to me.

Comment: Technically, the phrasing you use is lacking a pronoun (or other grammar) that connects "records" back to "game". You can fix it by breaking it into two sentences, as @J.R. did, or by using phrasing like you used in the title of your question: "X is a game for three players, for which the earliest records date back to 1500 B.C.". Or rephrase it to avoid using the cumbersome prepositional phrase "for which": "X is a game for three players which is first mentioned in the historical record around 1500 B.C." (I don't know why "for which" sounds cumbersome today; it probably didn't 100 years ago.)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with snailboat's comment; the phrasing in your title is much better than the one in the question body. In fact I wouldn't even really tweak it at all; I think you'd be just fine to say:

> [X] is an old game for 3 players, the earliest records **for** which date back to around 1500 B.C.

I made a tiny tweak to change *of* to *for*; I don't think *of* is necessarily wrong, but *for* sounds more natural to me.

You could also remove the reference to *records* entirely and stick with the *appeared* in your question body, something similar to what J.R. suggested:

> [X] is an old game for three players which first appeared around 1500 B.C.

Honestly I think the *dates back to* wording is much nicer than your second version with *appeared*. But either one gets your meaning across just fine!

Comment: I mostly agree with you except prefer *of* in place of that *for*.  With *of*, records clearly refers to the game.  With *for*, there may be a misimpression that the game is for players whose records date back to 1500 B.C.